# Passing dynamic secrect keys (change for every user) to module file in Nestjs

Tags: typescript, twilio, nestjs

I am giving TwilioModule in imports of another.module.ts
currently the account sid and token are hard coded, I want them to change for every user (passing here while finding it somewhere else). Please help.

````
    TwilioModule.forRoot({
      accountSid: "***********************",
      authToken:  "***********************",
    }),
  ];```
````

Answer (score 1):

that's what [async providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/async-providers) are meant for. Your `TwilioModule` must have an async version (let's say `TwilioModule.forRootAsync`). Or you could write a wrapper for it

See an example of how a dynamic module that expose an asnyc API here: https://dev.to/nestjs/advanced-nestjs-how-to-build-completely-dynamic-nestjs-modules-1370

Answer (score 0):

Just move logic with auth tokens to some auth service. You no need pass this tokens to a module.